# Jquery Mobile Slow IPAD Keyboard When Typing in Modal / Dialog

Tags: jquery, mobile

In the application we are building I noticed on iPad I noticed that when we fire a dialog which has text entry fields the keyboard on the IPAD severely lags. Has anyone run across this issue with JQUERY mobile and the keyboard with dialogs / popups.  I'm using the latest JQM which is currently 2.1. If you have what solutions do you recommend?

Thanks.